# 3 heads in a sequence when a fair coin is tossed 5 times

Tags: probability, self-study

Can someone help me with this one?

A fair coin is tossed 5 times, what is the probability of a sequence of 3 heads? I can see that there are 2*2*2*2*2 possible outcomes, but how many of these include 3 heads in a sequence and why?

Comment: There are only 32 combinations possible; you could write them all out and just count up the ones that have three heads in them.  You could save some effort by noting that all combinations with a tail in the third place cannot have a sequence of three heads, so you actually only have to write out 16 combinations (the ones with a head in the third place) and remember that the other 16 don't have any sequences of three heads.

Comment: Please count: FFFFF
FFFFT
FFFTF
FFFTT
FFTFF
FFTFT
FFTTF
FFTTT
FTFFF
FTFFT
FTFTF
FTFTT
FTTFF
FTTFT
FTTTF
FTTTT
TFFFF
TFFFT
TFFTF
TFFTT
TFTFF
TFTFT
TFTTF
TFTTT
TTFFF
TTFFT
TTFTF
TTFTT
TTTFF
TTTFT
TTTTF
TTTTT

Comment: Do you mean _exactly_ three successive Heads, or _three or more_ successive Heads? The answer are different in these two cases.

Comment: A general analysis of the problem of computing the chance of getting $k$ heads in a row out of a sequence of $n$ independent trials when each head has a chance of $p$ occurring is given in my reply at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/23762.  The approach given there gives $(3-2p)p^3$ = $1/4$ when $p=1/2$, $k=3$, and $n=5$.

Answer (score 3):

Total number of possible events = 2^5 = 32

Frequency of exactly 3 heads (HHHT*, THHHT, *THHH) = 2+1+2 = 5

Frequency of exactly four consecutive heads (HHHHT, THHHH) = 2

Frequency of five consecutive heads = 1

Frequency of required events = 5+2+1 = 8

Required probability = 8/32 = 1/4

Comment: Thanks to all those that have provided insights, I could indeed list all possible outcomes and count the one with at least 3 heads but I like the reasoning proposed by Stat-R.